# XSLT: Make paths resolve in the template/relative to the template

Tags: xslt

I have a template

```
<xsl:template name="template">
<xsl:param name="param"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which I call using

```
<xsl:call-template name="template">
<xsl:with-param name="param" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

This resolves the contents of . to a string, and passes them to the template.

However, it resolves . relative to the template call. If I change the context within the template, how can I make the parameter resolve within the template, relative to the new context?

---

Example added as per request:

```
<xsl:template name="template">
    <xsl:param name="param1"/>
    <xsl:param name="param2"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$param1">
        <xsl:value-of select="func:Lookup($param2)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:call-template name="template">
    <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="element"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

where param1 and param2 are relative xpaths.

What I want to do is pass both relative xpaths to the template, and then resolve them. `<xsl:for-each select="$param1">` should resolve to some elements, and then `.` should resolve relative to each element. $param2 should be resolved relative to $param1.

But what actually happens is both are resolved relative to the template call. This is okay for param1, but not for param2.

If it weren't for the for-each, I could pass `element/.` as param2. But this won't work because of the for-each.

Comment: It looks to me that whatever you want to do can be done much simpler. Maybe you can add an example of what you try to achieve.

Comment: I've considered string('.'), but then it doesn't resolve at all, even inside the template.

Comment: I've also considered setting a variable in the template, using `select` to take a string and return a node.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter value is actually a node (the current node) not a string, but you are right that (as in most languages) the parameter holds a value and not a fragment of syntax. If you really need to pass a string (or more commonly, a fragment of xpath extracted from the source) you need a dynamic evaluation extension such as axon:evaluate, many, but not all, products have such an extension. If the requirement is simple such as an element name) rather than arbitrary xpath you can pass a string such as

```
 <xsl:with-param name="paaram2" select="'foo'"/>
```

then use it as

```
<xsl:value-of select="func:Lookup(*[name()=$param2])"/>
```

which will pass the element `<foo/>` to the function.

Here, reading the expression from the inside out

```
 *
```

selects all the child elements of the current node

```
name()
```

then returns the name of that element so

```
[name()=$param2]
```

is true just for those child elements with name specified in the parameter, so

```
*[name()=$param2]
```

selects the elements with name specified by the parameter and

```
func:Lookup(*[name()=$param2])
```

applies the extension function to those elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't get it to work. Could you explain it? e.g. What is the `*` for? Why have you put `name()=$param2` instead of `name($param2)`? My understanding is that `name()` takes a node-set and returns a string, rather than the other way round. 

(Also, I think you should have `])` instead of `)]`.)

Thanks

Comment: sorry about the typo, fixed as you suggested and added line by line description of the expression

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. It doesn't work, unfortunately. I guess I need something like saxon:evaluate, as you suggest.

Comment: what doesn't work? It will work if you pass in an element name it won't work if you pass in an xpath fragment. What does you parameter look like?

Comment: I'm passing xpaths, e.g. `./ns0:id`.

I'm going to try `func:Lookup($param1/$param2)`.

Comment: well ./ns0:id is kind of an odd example as `./` at the start of a path never does anything and you could always replace that by ns0:id which would work, however yes in general it doesn't do paths. func:Lookup($param1/$param2) will not do what you want 9and is the same as func:Lookup($param2) except you repeat the value of $param2 if "param1 contains more than 1 node. If you always want a two step path and you don't want to use saxon@evaluate you need two string parameters and lookup(*[name()=$param1]/*[name()=$param2])